# How to return unique rows having count() of multiple columns = 1 using group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count

So here is my situation:

```
____________________________________________
|  idnumber |  name         |  sectiongroup |
--------------------------------------------
|     123   |  Joe          |      one      |
|     123   |  Barry        |      two      |
|     1234  |  Laura        |      one      |
|     1234  |  LauraCopyCat |      one      |
--------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to build a query which will return any unique (i.e. - `COUNT(idnumber) = 1`) id numbers in a given `sectiongroup`. So if you are in sectiongroup number one and no one else in your sectiongroup has the same ID number as you, then I want your idnumber. If someone in group two happens to have the same idnumer, that is okay, I still want your idnumber.

For example, Barry and Joe have the same id number but they are in separate sectiongroups, so I want to return their idnubers. However, Laura and LauraCopyCat have the SAME sectiongroup, so I do NOT want their idnumbers to be returned. So far I have the following:

```
SELECT idnumber
FROM namestable 
GROUP BY idnumber, sectiongroup
HAVING(COUNT(idnumber) = 1)
```

Is there a way to add sectiongroup into the COUNT()=1 condition?

Comment: And what's wrong with your current query?

Comment: Your query seems right to me .. what's the problem ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I think my expectations from the test data was wrong and not the query its self!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `COUNT(*)` to avoid confusion. This will count the number of records in the particular group. Remember, a group consists of the unique combinations of values in the fields specified in your `GROUP BY` statement.

```
SELECT idnumber
FROM namestable 
GROUP BY idnumber, sectiongroup
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Note that this will result in duplicate idnumbers, if you have records that share an id but have different subgroups. To remove duplicate, just change `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0a50c/3